# linq list string like

Tags: linq

I have a list:

```
List(Of String)
```

I want to filter it with LINQ.

I use things like this:

```
newList = (From l In myList Where l Like String.Format("%{0}%", value)).ToList
```

Value is something like `a` or `no`, etc.

I want something like a `LIKE` in SQL:

```
like "%a%"
```

So I that will result a list of string where there is a `a` in each string.

How should I do that?

```
dim list1 as list(of string)
list1.Add("aaa")
list1.Add("bbb")
list1.Add("ccc")
list1.Add("abc")
list1 = from l in list1 where ???? 'like "a" return list1 with 2 item : "aaa" and "abc"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List a = new List();

a = a.Where(item => item.contains("a")).ToList();

Comment: don't you mean a.Where(...) rather than a.Select(...)

Comment: and its in c# not in vb, I need it in vb

Comment: (From item In myList Where (item.Contains(value)) Select item).ToList()

Answer (score 1):

In C#:

```
var newList = originalList.Where(item => item.Contains("a")).ToList();
```

In VB.Net:

```
dim newList = originalList.Where(Function(item) item.Contains("a")).ToList
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   (From I in Mylist
   Where I.smth Contains(String)
   Select I);
```

For a list of String you can do that :

```
   (From I in Mylist
   Where I.smth Contains(String(0)) Or I.smth Contains(String(1))...
   Select I);
```

If you don't know how much strings you'll get, you might also need dynamic queries. It's quite more difficult and I won't be able to explain it